# TTF fonts: seeing the characters available

Tags: fonts, unicode

OK, newbie basic question.

I've installed [Junicode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/junicode/) TTF on Mac OSX 10.6. I now have it available as a system font. Brilliant. But how do I:

- see the characters that are available to in the font
- actually enter them?

It's a medieval font with a bunch of characters that have no equivalent on modern keyboards. First, I don't know how to view the characters to pick the ones I need, and second, I don't know how to enter them in my Word documents! (Unicode? But how do I work out the Unicode -> symbol mapping?)

There is no handy reference guide from Junicode itself. If I open the TTF with the default Mac application, it doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try the [Character Palette](http://davidlowry.co.uk/charmap-for-mac-os-x/)? If it works like Character Map on windows, it will list all available characters in the font, and let you copy & paste them into a text file if you want.

Answer (score 0):

open font book and select preview then select repetoire