# Glyph overview of True Type Font

Tags: linux, truetype-fonts

Similarly to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/159195/198080), I would like to have an overview of all glyphs of a True Type Font (TTF). I know how to achieve this for Type 1 fonts (via LaTeX), and for Open Type Fonts (OTF) via

```
cfftot1 Font.otf | t1testpage | epstopdf --filter > glyphs.pdf
```

using LCDFTools.

How can I do the same for True Type Fonts? Ideally, I would get a PDF with all glyphs together with their name, just as in the OTF case.

Comment: if your question has a duplicate, please do not make a new question.

Comment: @Znau It is not a duplicate, I wrote "similarly". The linked question asks for a Mac solution, and got a Max answer. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: must have misread then. GL solving your problem.

Comment: So... you're looking for a Linux solution? Windows? Please specify in what respect the linked question doesn't work for you, *and what you're looking for instead*.